# Segmentation fault in sqlite3_prepare() dependent on sql string

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I am writing a C++ program which will interact with a SQLite3 database and am getting an error that I do not understand.  To preface, while I am relatively experienced with C++, I am brand new to SQLite3 and everything else SQL.  I have isolated the problem to the very first actual SQL code I try to prepare for execution.  The code below includes everything relevant (as far as I can tell, anyway) up until the point of failure.  The #includes are not shown because this is a function within a larger program.

```
int initDB()
{
        FILE *file;
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        if (file = fopen("cellEvents.db", "r")) // Check if database file already exists, deleting if found
        {
                fclose(file);
                remove("cellEvents.db");
        }
        sqlite3 *db;                            // Create pointer to database object
        char *zErrMsg = 0;                      // Create pointer to store error data
        int rc;                                 // Create character to store return value of open function
        string sql;
        rc = sqlite3_open("cellEvents.db", &db);        // Attempt to open database
    
        if( rc ){                               // If an error occurred
                cout << "DB Error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
                sqlite3_close(db);
                return(0);
        }

        //sql = u8"CREATE TABLE events(" \
              "ID INT PRIMARY Key NOT NULL," \
              "lower_index INTEGER NOT NULL," \
              "upper_index INTEGER NOT NULL," \
              "lower_bound REAL NOT NULL," \
              "upper_bound REAL NOT NULL," \
              "area REAL NOT NULL," \
              "num_peaks INTEGER NOT NULL," \
              "MCE INTEGER NOT NULL," \
              "peak1 REAL NOT NULL," \
              "peak2 REAL," \
              "peak3 REAL," \
              "peak4 REAL," \
              "peak5 REAL," \
              "time_data TEXT NOT NULL," \
              "voltage_data TEXT NOT NULL);"; 


        sql = u8"CREATE TABLE events(ID INT PRIMARY Key NOT NULL)";
        //sql = u8"HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD ";

        cout << "The prepared command is \"" << sql << "\"" << endl;

        cout << "Attempting to prepare SQL command" << endl;
        sqlite3_prepare(db, sql.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL);
```

There are three different values assigned to the string sql (two are commented); one is the command I would like to actually execute (the long CREATE TABLE string); one is a small fragment of that string; and one is simply "HELLO WORLD" looped to be the same length as the fragment.  The program compiles with no errors regardless of which value of sql is uncommented, but the only one which does not produce a segmentation fault at runtime, specifically at the line where sqlite3_prepare() is called, is the "HELLO WORLD" string.  I am at a loss to what could possibly cause this.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried your code, but there was no crash, even with *Address Sanitizer*, and I don't see an error in it.

Comment: How weird.  I copied this all to make a smaller test program and it worked, just like you said.  I suppose it must be something in the larger program.  Thanks!  I still don't know what the problem is, but at least I can stop debugging this particular function haha.